# Why is one of these dynamic programming implementations of the Fibonacci sequence faster than the other?

Tags: c++, fibonacci, gmp

I've been researching and benchmarking various Fibonacci algorithms recently for my own amusement and more or less by accident came up with an alternate implementation of the classic O(n) time and O(1) space dynamic programming implementation.

Consider the following two functions:

```
BigInt fib_dp_classic(int n) {
  if (n == 0) {
    return 0;
  }

  BigInt x = 0, y = 1, z;
  for (int i = 2; i <= n; ++i) {
    z = x + y;
    x = y;
    y = z;
  }

  return y;
}
```

and

```
BigInt fib_dp_mod(int n) {
  BigInt x = 0, y = 1, z = 1;
  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    switch (i % 3) {
      case 0:
        y = x + z;
        break;
      case 1:
        z = x + y;
        break;
      case 2:
        x = y + z;
        break;
    }
  }

  switch (n % 3) {
    case 0:
      return x;
      break;
    case 1:
      return y;
      break;
    case 2:
      return z;
      break;
  }
}
```

On my machine, calculating the millionth Fibonacci number takes 6.55s with fib_dp_classic and 2.83 seconds with fib_dp_mod, and even turning on -O3 doesn't change this too much. I don't really have any good ideas as to why the mod version is faster. Is it because the extra store instructions in the classic version are more expensive than the mod in the second? It's my understanding that the compiler should be putting all three variables in registers in both versions and computing the mod is actually fairly expensive; is this not the case?

In fact, I just put both of these through [compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/g/F1B2Q8) and both are using only registers once you turn optimizations on. Granted, this is only using ints, not the GMP-based bigints I was actually using for my benchmark. Is there some weird GMP implementation detail that might be the cause here?

Update: I even strace'd both to see if malloc() might be the culprit and fib_dp_classic uses 130 syscalls (for n=1000000) while fib_dp_mod uses 133. So still no real clues...

Update 2: Yes, the buffer copies are the culprit (as geza pointed out) and I was dumb for not realizing. Here are two alternate versions and their benchmark results:

```
BigInt fib_dp_move(int n) {
  if (n == 0) {
    return 0;
  }

  BigInt x = 0, y = 1, z;
  for (int i = 2; i <= n; ++i) {
    z = std::move(x) + y;
    x = std::move(y);
    y = std::move(z);
  }

  return y;
}
```

This runs in 2.84 seconds, so just about equivalent to the mod version since it eliminates the unnecessary copies.

```
BigInt fib_dp_swap(int n) {
  if (n == 0) {
    return 0;
  }

  BigInt x = 0, y = 1, z;
  for (int i = 2; i <= n; ++i) {
    z = x + y;
    swap(x, y);
    swap(y, z);
  }

  return y;
}
```

This (from geza) also runs in 2.84 seconds, so again about equivalent to the mod version since it eliminates the copies in basically the same way, just calling `swap()` instead of using move semantics.

Comment: Compiler Explorer doesn't support GMP yet. So for now it doesn't show native of your GMP version. Apparently, two loads of GMP's BigInt are what the classic pays more than mod version. Perhaps you may want to configure your own CE to look inside the native of those BigInt loads.

Comment: I wonder, if you'd implement the 2nd version with `long int` and calculate only within its range, but several times, each (to compensate for the short time it takes to calculate), which one will be faster?

Comment: My advice would be to learn how to use a profiler. It may take a bit of time the first time, but it is a very useful skill and can easily answer such questions.

Comment: I think you can even be faster than that by moving out of the for loop the 2 first iterations (which are no-op btw), and then increment `i` by `3` at each iteration, and do the computation for `x`,`y` and `z` (in that order) in a single iteration. This will avoid the modulo 3 and the switch case in the inner loop, I think it can make a difference (and would be interested to know about the results!).

Comment: @OlivierSohn: it won't make a difference for the GMP case. 99.9% of time spent in GMP, the "driver" routine doesn't matter.

Comment: @geza maybe it will allow the compiler to do some more optimizations, and I don't believe the 99.9% is correct : it would mean that only 2 nanoseconds, on average are used by the non-bigint operations of the loop. I doubt that.

Comment: @OlivierSohn: fib(1000000) is a ~86kb number. It is **much** slower to work with than a simple modulo (which is optimized to a multiply anyway) + `switch`. Maybe 99.9% is an exaggeration, but surely it is more than 99%. So even if you remove the driver routine, the speedup will be less than 1%.

Comment: @geza maybe some branch mispredictions are also penalizing the loop.

Comment: @OlivierSohn: the bottleneck is not there. Sure, you can speed the routine up, but for Fib(1000000), the speedup will be at most 1% (presumably much less).

Comment: @geza I'm trying to benchmark this, do you have any idea where I can find BigInt? doesn't seem to be in gmp headers...

Comment: @OlivierSohn: I don't know, it's a proprietary interface to GMP perhaps. You maybe want to use the `gmpxx.h` headers in GMP, and the class `mpz_class`, it's very easy to use.

Comment: @Mark Schott, can you please indicate what `BigInt` is in your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, there is no point comparing the GMP version with the simple int version. Fib(1000000) is a ~86KB number, it is **much** slower to work with than a simple `int`. For `int`s, a copy can be basically free operation in certain circumstances, while for GMP numbers, it involves a copy of a 86KB buffer.

(Note, of course, the copy won't be 86KB always. In the beginning, it is ~0KB, but as the routine progresses, it grows to 86KB. And as the numbers grow, the routine becomes slower and slower, so the majority of the time is spent when the number is big)

Assuming a quality `BigInt` implementation, we have these operation counts in each iteration:

- fib_dp_classic: 1 add, 2 copies
- fib_dp_mod: 1 add

As you can see, the classic version does 2 extra copies (note, that in a quality implementation, `x=y+z` doesn't involve a copy). And the speed of a copy has the same order of magnitude as the add (I mean, an add may be 2x-3x slower than a copy). So this explains the ~2.3x slowdown of the classic routine.

Note, that if `BigInt` would be an implementation which uses reference counts, then `x=y` operation could be basically a free operation, because it doesn't need a copy, just incrementing a counter (In this case, the classic routine would have the same speed as the mod one).

Last note: presumably you can speed up the classic version, if a non-copying `swap` operation is available:

```
BigInt fib_dp_swap(int n) {
  if (n == 0) {
    return 0;
  }

  BigInt x = 0, y = 1, z;
  for (int i = 2; i <= n; ++i) {
    z = x + y;
    x.swap(y); // Note the 2 swaps here
    y.swap(z);
  }

  return y;
}
```

With gmpxx, this routine runs in the same time as the mod version, and much simpler.

It is because a `swap` operation can be much cheaper than a copy. Swap just needs to swap the pointers inside `BigInt`, while a copy needs a ~86KB memory-copy.

Comment: In gmp, is there no way to construct BigInt object "in place" without deallocation/allocation everytime we do `z = x + y;` ?

Comment: @sandthorn: I don't think that GMP will reallocate every time. But, reallocation strategy is suboptimal, because the allocated space grows linearly, instead of exponentially. Supposedly the routine can be faster, if `x`, `y` and `z` had the necessary space preallocated. But I don't know how to achieve this cleanly.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, I feel dumb for not realizing how big these buffers are and how different this is from the trivial `int` case. Updating my answer to include a few other optimizations, including your swap() idea.

Answer (score 7):

Your first function uses one addition and 3 copies for `BigInt` -- all of the are quite time consuming operations. The second function uses one addition and one copy operations -- that's where the savings come from, you save 2 copy operations with `BigInt`.

Comment: Is it OK if I edit your answer and try to simplify it?

Comment: @Gox what part seems too complicated to you ?

Comment: btw, what is `BigInt`? How "big" is it? (in term of size? is it dynamically allocated?)

Comment: @OlivierSohn please, use google or open another question?

Comment: @lenik `BigInt` is used in the question, but it's not indicated what it is, so it's totally appropriate to ask here (and btw, you answer assumes an implementation of `BigInt`, so it may not be relevant depending on the actual implementation).

Answer (score 0):

Its a case of data dependency in your classic each iteration takes two cycles as

```
z = x + y;
x = y; // depends on y from previous loop.
y = z; // depends on z
```

in the mod case each iteration depends only on the previous so it can do one per cycle.

Also the %3 is not really a modulo 3 but some compiler magic that makes it a simple operation. In fact you can properbly optimize it more by writing

```
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i+=3) {
      y = x + z;
      z = x + y;
      x = y + z;
    }
  }
```

The cost of the extra calculations will be saved in the extra control logic.